# mod_rewrite: How to get all requests and send to a PHP script for routing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need the Rewrite settings and rules for getting all server/URL requests and send them to a PHP script, and later route the requests from that PHP.

Is this possible and how?

I have the following, but with this I can't process all requests to my PHP script:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) router.php?first_request=$1
```

You get the idea what I want...

Answer (score 2):

Put these rewrite rules to your .htaccess file, which would redirect all requests which are not pointing to valid directory or file to your specific script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_php_file.php?url=$1
```

From your script you can obtain value of the url variable $_GET['url'] and split it as needed.